# Primefaces Datatable coloring row

Tags: jsf, primefaces

*closedItem* returns `Boolean`.
I add this to *dataTable*

```
rowStyleClass="#{(res.closedItem) eq true ? 'Closed' : null}"
```

**My CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .Closed
    {
        background-color: #6CE26C !important;
        background-image: none !important;
        color: #000000 !important;
    }
</style>
```

But it doesn't work, pls help.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
rowStyleClass="#{res.closedItem ? 'Closed' : ''}"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the possibility to use the PrimeFaces framework?

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/rowColor.xhtml

Take a look at it, there are some very nice additional features